# joomla css not working in gmail

Tags: php, joomla

I am adding style to my mail template in joomla with style tag, but it is not work in gmail.
but if i added it as inline style it works fine. 
Anybody please help

thanks.

Comment: That's the way E-Mail works. Inline styles are the only reliable way to go.

Comment: You might want to consider the info here: http://www.email-standards.org/

Answer (score 2):

Read here more about mail templates markup rules http://www.sitepoint.com/designers-guide-html-email/

Mail templates markup is a little bit different from browser's markup.
Do not use `div`, for examlpe. You nedd to use nasty `table` instead.